# Dependent picklist values not generating in visualforce

Tags: visualforce, error, dependent-picklist, bug

For past couple weeks, with latest version of Chrome, I've been getting Browser Console errors for `picklist4.js` library in Salesforce. The error happens to occur randomly, and not always, and the only solution I could find was to reload the page.

When this error occurs, the Dependent Picklist values are all empty. This seems to be happening with other users of Salesforce as well. So I'm looking for some expert or salesforce team to take a look at this - [SFDC Developer Forums ~ Thread](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9060G000000IAg6QAG&feedtype=RECENT_REPLY&dc=Developer_Forums&criteria=OPENQUESTIONS&).

It seems to have started happening with latest v57 of Google Chrome and provide us any workaround for this or confirm as an ongoing issue which can be fixed in platform?

[image]

Comment: Are you under any proxy network, usually they block some JavaScript files.

Comment: No, not using any proxy or vpn network. It has been working fine some couple of weeks back. And I even confirmed the error happening with `no extensions` loaded for Chrome.

Comment: Could you try in a different browser or Chrome's incognito mode?

Comment: Already tried that, different browser (FF) works ok. Even Chrome v56 works fine as well. Chrome Incognito mode also exhibit same error.